# GTM fires some tags in debug mode only

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a website where I need to track a users path through a bunch of pages.

Those pages have several elements (text fields, buttons, select, etc.) and I decided to create a virtual pageview when each of those elements is used. Like - /step1, /step2 and so on.

As some of those elements appear with AJAX depending on users actions, I've made a custom HTML tag that checks if element with a specific class was loaded and then it pushes custom event to dataLayer. Then there is a rule for that custom event which triggers standard Google Analytics reporting tag with custom page path and page name set.

It's driving me crazy, cause while in GTM debug mode - everything works perfect. Elements being identified, virtual pageviews being created, data is being successfully passed to GA. Whenever I publish container - it stops working. However, basic tags like standard GA reporting or click event tracking are fired just fine.

Any ideas ? Maybe there are methods or tools to debug GTM behavior without debug mode on ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The main difference between DEBUG MODE and NORMAL MODE is that the Debug mode evaluates ALL your variables, ALL the time. But when you quit Preview Mode and that your GA Tracking is working with the published version of your container, the variables are evaluated ONLY if they are linked to a triggered tag (or the trigger of a triggered tag).

Comment: This is actually for me the most complete answer. It is not commonly known that Variables are being triggered a lot in debug mode.

Answer (score 3):

Note for myself and other easily distracted people:

1. Make sure that you have rights to publish changes
2. Make sure you're not only create a version but also publish it...

Comment: Those are two important notes :)

Comment: Very important :) ... AND if you have implementation from a  preview share like `...&gtm_auth=XXXXX&gtm_preview=env-17...` in your gtm script dont forget to change the `env-XX` version

Answer (score 1):

In case multiple container environments exists tags may only be limited to triggering to the environment snippet which is dedicated for staging or live only.
Check if containers are limited to triggering on either staging / live or other environments.